# jade.Как отключить минификацию при компиляции?

Tags: jade, минификация

Недавно начал учить препроцессоры. Столкнулся с проблемой:
При компиляции из `.jade` в `.html` код минифицируется. Что для обучения не очень хорошо.
Как отключить минификацию? Желательно обьяснение на пальцах.
P.S: пишу код наPHPStorm, использую встроенный Watcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gulp.task('jade', function () {
  return gulp.src('public/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(gulpJade({
      jade: jade,
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'))
})
```

Comment: Для полноты картины выделите конкретную деталь, которая вызывает нужный эффект. И совсем в идеале приложите ссылку на документацию, которая описывает опции (в т. ч. эту).